# Possible or not? Jordan chain does not span the full generalised eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

Given a matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and a corresponding eigenvector $v_1$:

1. Is it possible that the Jordan chain $v_1$ generates does **not** span the full generalised eigenspace of $A$ w.r.t $\lambda$? ie. There exists some vector $v$ that is not in the span of the vectors in that Jordan chain?

Here's an example I came up with, but I'm not sure if I made any mistake:

Let $A=\text{zero matrix}$, then $(1,0,...,0)$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $0$, but it only generates a Jordan chain of length 1 (only contains itself), since the range of $(A-\lambda I)$ only contains $0$.

2. If 1. is true, then how could we find all vectors in the full generalised eigenspace of $A$ with respect to $\lambda$?

For example, it's possible that for some matrix A and eigenvalue $\lambda$, there is some $v_1$ such that $Av_1=\lambda v_1$ but $v_1$ only generates a Jordan chain of say length 3, while $(A-\lambda I)$ has nullity 4, then how could we find a 4th generalised eigenvector?

here full generalised eigenspace = set of all generalised eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda$ together with the zero vector.

Comment: You need as many chains as the dimension of the Eigenspace; each chain gives you a Jordan block, each Jordan block gives you an eigenvector.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for your reply! But I want to know if each Jordan chain spans the *full generalised eigenspace*, which is $\left \{ v: (A- \lambda I)^iv=0 \text{ for some }i\in\mathbb{N} \right \}$. In particular, I want to know if my counterexample is valid.

Comment: And I answered that. You don't need to put in italics, because I heard you the first time and I answered you. A single chain will only give you a subspace of dimension $1$ of the **eigenspace**, so you need as many chains to span the generalized eigenspace as the dimension of the eigenspace. If $\dim(N(A-\lambda I))=k$, then you need $k$ chains, ending in $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors, to span the generalized eigenspace. I don't know what you are trying to find a "counterexample" to, because you asked a question, you did not posit a statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again and sorry for the confusion. My statement is "It is possible that a Jordan chain does not span the full generalised eigenspace of A w.r.t λ". But I think it's possible sometimes. For example, take the JCF $M=\begin{pmatrix}
3 &  1&0 \\ 
 0& 3 & 1\\ 
 0&0  & 3
\end{pmatrix}$ and the standard basis $b_1,b_2,b_3$ of $\mathbb{C}^3$, ${b_1,b_2,b_3}$ is a Jordan chain and it already span the full generalised eigenspace.

Comment: Questions don't have counterexamples, they have answers. And I've answered it twice, so here goes the **third** time: you need as many chains as the dimension of the eigenspace. Your example has eigenspace of dimension **one**, so **one** 
 (well-chosen) chain will suffice. The zero matrix has eigenspace of dimension $n$, so you need $n$ chains. As I have now said three times: *You need as many chains as the dimension of the eigenspace*. Which part of that sentence continues to be unclear?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry for bothering you so long. It appears that I've misunderstood some concepts and I think I've figured it out. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your patience.